# Display username to logged in user only?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have a Wordpress blog set up to display comments as "Anonymous User" by hard coding it into the comments.php file.  I would like to have it say the user's Username next to their comment and ONLY display that Username to THEM.  In other words, if they're a guest, they'll see "Anonymous User" and if they're a registered/logged in DIFFERENT user, they'll still see "Anonymous User", but if it's THEIR comment it'll say "Your Comment" or their own username.  Any clue on a snippet of code?  Here's what I have so far:

`Anonymous User: <div class="post-txt" id="<?php comment_ID() ?>"><?php comment_text() ?></div>`

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find your solution here? If yes, please mark which answer you selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function my_custom_comment_author_filter($author){
  global $current_user;
  wp_get_current_user();
  if(!is_category(3)){
    return $author;
  }
  if(0 == $current_user->ID || ($current_user->display_name !== $author && $current_user->user_login !== $author)){
    return 'Anonymous User';
  }
  return $author;
}

add_filter('get_comment_author', 'my_custom_comment_author_filter');
```

Comment: you'll need a 'varies: Cookie' header if you allow any caching.

Comment: @symcbean true.
Also, if you want the comments to show the post author's name to everybody, you'll need to add another check against the author. Also, it might be a good idea to use only the comment author's name, not the comment author's link.

Comment: Ok so I tried this way, and at first I was getting an error so I had to remove the = sign between the first two words (function = my_custom...) and then it threw another error, unexpected $end, so I added a second close } after the last one and before the add_filter.  Now, no more errors, but, when I try to put my new function in my theme file, I get another error, telling me that it requires args.  I'm not sure what args to use.  I was typing "<?php my_custom_comment_author_filter() ?>" but apparently that wasn't working.  Any ideas?  thanks much!

Comment: yes. You need to keep the $author in the function declaration. That's how the argument is passed into the function. I'll edit the answer to reflect your changes. Sorry about those. I guess I just missed them...

Comment: Ok well for some weird reason adding this to my functions.php file and not doing anything else applies this to the Admin dashboard (comments section).  Any idea why?  I only want this function to work for the front end.  I want anybody who has access to the back end be able to see the correct usernames.

Comment: Also, what if I want this to be category specific?  So let's say Cat-1 has a specific comment form and Cat-3 has a different one.  How do I use this only for Cat-1?

Comment: @RodeoRamsey that probably has something to do with your comments theme file. If it's not using the comment_author() function, this filter wouldn't be triggered. I've added a check for categories. If you only want it to work on a specific category, put the ID, name, or slug of the category where the number 3 is. You can also check for multiple categories by using an array as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you will need to get the comment author's ID, get the logged in user's ID and compare the two. Have a look at [getting the current logged in user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) and [getting information about the current comment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment) from the Codex.

I haven't tested this snippet, but it should point you in the right direction:

```
<?php global $user_id, $user_login; 
    get_currentuserinfo();  // This will populate $user_id with the logged in user's ID or '' if not logged in
    $the_comment = get_comment(comment_ID());  // Get a comment Object...
    $author_id = $the_comment->user_id; // and extract the commenter's ID

    if($user_id !== '' && $author_id == $user_id){
        echo 'Your comment [ ' . $user_login . ' ]:';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Anonymous User:';
    }
?>
```

Comment: John P. Bloch's answer above is really nice. Adding that to your functions.php file would allow you to call that anywhere.

Comment: I tried the above answer and couldn't get it working so I tried your answer to see if it would work and it seems to add a digit next to the Anonymous User text but it doesn't display correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you try echoing out $user_id, $author_id and $user_login to see what comes back? Are you seeing the current logged in user's details and the comment author's ID?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the current visitor is logged in
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    ....
} else {
    ....
} ?>
```

Comment: Well, that only works to let me know if I'm logged in or not but it doesn't separate the two conditional statements.

I think that's the right start, but I'm thinking it needs to say something like "if user is logged in, AND, user name is = to same login" but I have no idea how to code that...